# Does it make sense to combine optional with reference_wrapper?

Tags: c++, pointers, reference, option-type, std

It occurred to me that in C++ it is possible to use the type `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>`. An object of this type is essentially a reference to an object of type `T` or a null value, i.e., pretty much a pointer. My questions:

1. Is there any conceptual difference between `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>` and `T*`?
2. Is there any practical difference? Are there situations where it might be advisable to choose `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>` over `T*`?

Comment: Yes, it makes sense. There is no `optional<T&>`, so `optional< reference_wrapper<T> >` is the closest we have. That conveys non-ownership, no uninitialised values, no accidental construct from `nullptr`, no accidental arithmetic, no ugliness with `*`, `->`, and co. (albeit some *other* ugliness due to having to eschew `auto` when looping, use `.get()` if the context doesn't supply the wanted conversion, etc.). These are all concrete benefits to both semantics and safety. Just `optional<T&>` would be more concise, but then we'll be wondering why we could put that in a container but not `T&`....

Answer (score 18):

> Is there any conceptual difference between `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>` and `T*`?

`std::optional<>`, as the name already suggest, is meant to be used when we could have a value or might not have any value at all.

The equivalent of *having no value* for a `T*` object would be assigning `nullptr` to it, i.e.: the pointer will point to *nowhere*, as opposed to *somewhere* (or even *anywhere*, i.e.: uninitialized). It can be said that `std::optional<>` exports the concept of `nullptr` for pointers to any arbitrary type. So, I would say they are conceptually very similar, being the `std::option<>` approach a kind of generalization.

> Is there any practical difference? Are there situations where it might be advisable to choose `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>` over `T*`?

I can think of the size. `std::optional<>` contains an internal flag for indicating the presence/absence of a value, whereas for `T*` the `nullptr` is encoded directly as one of the values the pointer can store. So a `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>` object will be larger than a `T*`.

When it comes to safety, unlike `T*`, `std::optional<>` provides the member function `value()` which throws an exception if there is no value (it provides as well as the unsafe `operator*()` as `T*` does).

Also, using `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>` instead of `T*` , for example, as a function's return value may indicate in a *more explicit* way that there might be no value at all.

Answer (score 15):

The main difference between `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>` and `T*` is that with `T*` you have to think about who owns the memory that is pointed to.

If a function returns `T*` you have to know if you are responsible for freeing the memory or someone else is. That's not something you have to be concerned with when it's a reference.

Comment: Unless you are interacting with some pure c library, heap memory is pretty much always owned by `unique_ptr`, or `shared_ptr`, some kind of pool or container like `vector`.

Comment: "heap memory is pretty much always owned by unique_ptr, or shared_ptr" <- This is rather a convention that you can trust or not at your own peril.
As @TimK said, that with std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>> you don't own the memory is the semantics of the C++ language.

Answer (score 0):

There is some other difference.  With T * you have two states.  The pointer points to a valid object or to nullptr, which means empty.

With std::optionalstd::reference_wrapper<T> you have a third state : Uninitialized, where the pointer itself has no state yet.

Imagine like this :

```
void foo( std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<T>>& ref)
{
if (!ref)
{  // still not initialized
  initialize_reference(ref);
}
```

Now that you do have the reference set up, you can check if it has valid pointer or not.