# Modern C++ approach for providing optional arguments

Tags: c++, pointers, option-type, semantics, optional-parameters

Let's take the following function declaration:

```
void print(SomeType const* i);
```

Here, the `const*` nature of the argument `i` suggest the intent, that the parameter is *optional*, since it may be `nullptr`. If this was not intended, the argument would instead just be a `const&`. Communicating *optional*-semantics were certainly not the original intent for designing pointers, but using them to do so happens to work just fine for a long time.

Now, since using raw pointers is generally discouraged in modern C++ (and should be avoided in favor of `std::unique_ptr` and `std::shared_ptr` to precisely indicate particular *ownership*-semantics), I wonder how to properly indicate function parameters' *optional*-semantics **without passing by value**, i. e. **copying**, as

```
void print(std::optional<SomeType> i);
```

would do.

After thinking about it for a while I came up with the idea of using:

```
void print(std::optional<SomeType const&> i);
```

This would in fact be most precise. But it turns out that `std::optional` [cannot have reference types](https://www.fluentcpp.com/2018/10/05/pros-cons-optional-references/).¹

Also, using

```
void print(std::optional<SomeType> const& i);
```

would in no way be optimal, since then we would *require* our `SomeType` to exists in an `std::optional` on the *caller*-side, again possibly (or rather *likely*) requiring a copy *there*.

**Question:** So what would be a nice modern approach for allowing optional arguments without copying? Is using a raw pointer here still a reasonable approach in modern C++?

---

¹: Ironically the depicted reason for why `std::optional` cannot have reference types (controversy about rebinding or forwarding on assignment) does not apply in the case of `std::optional`s of *const* references, since they cannot be assigned to.

Comment: Try `optional< reference_wrapper<T> >` if you must

Comment: For your footnote: In theory you actually could define an `operator=(...) const`, nothing in the language prevents it, although good sense ought to :-) But even ignoring that, you have the same problem as for non-const references that rebinding would be inconsistent with what happens for value-based optional and therefore possibly surprising for many users.

Comment: Did you mean `std::shared_ptr` instead of `std::smart_ptr`?

Comment: "using raw pointers is generally discouraged in modern C++ " Disagree.  _Owning_ raw pointers is discouraged, but non-owning pointers are usually fine

Comment: Also there's `std::optional<std::cref< SomeType>>`, but I'd just use `SomeType*` for optional parameters.

Comment: @MooingDuck I think you mean `std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const SomeType>>`, though. `std::cref` [is just the helper function](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/functional/ref).

Answer (score 24, accepted):

Accepting a raw pointer is perfectly fine and is still done in plenty of "modern" codebases (which I'll note is a fast-moving target).  Just put a comment on the function saying that it's allowed to be null and whether the function holds a copy of the pointer after the call (i.e. what are the lifetime requirements for the pointed-to value).

Comment: Indeed using a raw pointer in modern codebases is in some sense clearer than ever - in the past that might have meant something about lifetimes, but in modern C++ you know that's not the case because you would've used a RAII wrapper (like `unique_ptr` to transfer ownership or `shared_ptr` to keep lifetime alive after the function returns). A comment about lifetimes, as you suggested, still wouldn't hurt though.

Comment: There is still `observer_ptr` to avoid confusion with raw pointer where we don't know if it is an old usage or not.

Comment: Another issue with pointers (raw and sometime with smart too) is to know if it is an array or a reference to a single element.

Comment: @Jarod42: If it's an array, it should be `Sometype[]`, and the next parameter should be a length parameter, which avoids the confusion

Comment: Instead of an array address + length pair of arguments, I would almost always take in `std::span<Sometype>` argument.

Comment: Clarity can also be added by making the raw pointer version private and exposing two overloads to the public, one using a reference/smart pointer of the specified type and one without any parameter, no confusion to the external user about ownership and its clear that its optional.

Comment: @MooingDuck: Try to differentiate between taking an optiolnal char vs a C-string: `const char*` for both. (indeed using `[]` make it clearer we expect an array, but not sure that convention was/is very used).

Answer (score 6):

Does function overloading provide a clean solution here?  E.g. To declare both the const ref and empty param list versions of the function?
This may depend on what the function body does in the no argument/null case - and how you can manage the two implementations to minimize code overlap.

Comment: In simple cases, certainly. However, I was aiming for a universal solution (also see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64443556#comment113953416_64444233) comment).

Answer (score 5):

Raw pointers are usually fine for this type of optional argument passing, actually one of the only times it is fine to use raw pointers overall. This is also the canonical recommended way.

That being said, `boost::optional` does allow you to use reference optional and const reference optionals. It was decided against to have this feature in the `std` library (for reasons I leave out here).

Answer (score 2):

This is actually what std::reference_wrapper was made for. Also see [Does it make sense to combine optional with reference_wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48721313/does-it-make-sense-to-combine-optional-with-reference-wrapper) for more reasoning as to when to use it, and when not to use it.

Answer (score 0):

> Here, the `const*` nature of the argument `i` suggest the intent, **that the parameter is optional** since it may be nullptr.
>
> [...]
>
> So what would be a nice modern approach for allowing optional arguments without copying?

Allowing an optional argument (not in the `std::optional` sense, but in the semantic sense) with differing implementation variations based on whether the optional argument is present or not sound like an ideal candidate for overloading:

```
struct SomeType { int value; };

namespace detail {
    void my_print_impl(const SomeType& i) {
        std::cout << i.value;
    }    
}  // namespace detail

void my_print() {
    const SomeType default_i{42};
    detail::my_print_impl(default_i);
}

void my_print(const SomeType& i) { 
    detail::my_print_impl(i);
}
```

or

```
namespace detail {
    void my_print_impl() {
        std::cout << "always print me\n";
    }    
}  // namespace detail

void my_print() {
    detail::my_print_impl();
}

void my_print(const SomeType& i) {
    detail::my_print_impl();
    std::cout << "have some type: " << i.value;
}
```

or some similar variation, depending on what your implementation should do depending on the existence/non-existence of the optional argument.

---

Optional references, otherwise, are basically raw pointers, and the latter may just as well be used (if overloading is not applicable).

Comment: In the case of simple functions (which my sparse example admittedly suggests), I certainly see overloading as an appropriate solution. However in the general case, the optional argument may only be used for a single case distinction in a more complex function, making (almost similar) overloads somewhat clunky. Also in the general case, there may be multiple optional arguments which may be specified independently of each other.