# prevent initializing std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const T>> with rvalue std::optional<T>

Tags: c++, dangling-pointer, stdoptional

`std::reference_wrapper` cannot be bound to rvalue reference to prevent dangling pointer.
However, with combination of `std::optional`, it seems that rvalue could be bound.

That is, `std::is_constructible_v<std::reference_wrapper<const int>, int&&>)` is `false` but `std::is_constructible_v<std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const int>>, std::optional<int>&&>` is `true`.

Here's an example:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <optional>

auto make() -> std::optional<int>
{
    return 3;
}

int main()
{
    std::optional<std::reference_wrapper<const int>> opt = make();
    if (opt)
        std::cout << opt->get() << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

I expected this code will be rejected by compiler, but it compiles well and `opt` contains dangling pointer.

Is this a bug of standard library? Or, is it just not possible to prevent dangling pointer here because of some kind of limitaion of C++ language specification?

If it is a bug of standard library, how can I fix it when I implement my own `optional` type?

It it's a limitation of current C++ specification, could you tell me where this problem comes from?

Comment: This is not a bug. Code is invalid, but problem is not located in std, but in this example. When someone uses `std::reference_wrapper` he should be aware of consequences and handle this with care.

Comment: I would say `template<class U> constexpr optional(const optional<U>&)` is still viable whereas `template<class U> constexpr optional(optional<U>&&)` does not participate in overload resolution.

Comment: On other hand clang complains: https://godbolt.org/z/xovxT5Ezo - correction https://godbolt.org/z/McTM1h74f

Comment: @MarekR: with clang 14, but no longer with clang 15...

Comment: yes just notice that.

Comment: @MarekR Your first link also compiles if `#include <functional>` is added.

Comment: Something maybe relevant to you: [Does it make sense to combine optional with reference_wrapper?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/48721313/does-it-make-sense-to-combine-optional-with-reference-wrapper)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

@Jarod42 already pointed out the core reason why this code compiles, but I will elaborate a bit.

The following two constructor templates for `std::optional<T>` are relevant to this question:

```
template <class U>
constexpr optional(const optional<U>& other)
requires std::is_constructible_v<T, const U&>;  // 1

template <class U>
constexpr optional(optional<U>&& other);
requires std::is_constructible_v<T, U>;         // 2
```

Note that the *requires-clauses* above are for exposition only. They might not be present in the actual declarations provided by the library implementation. However, the standard requires constructor templates 1 and 2 to only participate in overload resolution when the corresponding `std::is_constructible_v` constraint is satisfied.

The second overload will not participate in overload resolution because `std::reference_wrapper<const int>` is not constructible from `int` (meaning an rvalue of type `int`), which is the feature that is intended to prevent dangling references. However, the first overload *will* participate, because `std::reference_wrapper<const int>` is constructible from `const int&` (meaning an lvalue of type `const int`). The problem is that, when `U` is deduced and the `std::optional<int>` rvalue is bound to the `const optional<U>&` constructor argument, its rvalueness is "forgotten" in the process.

How might this issue be avoided in a user-defined `optional` template? I think it's possible, but difficult. The basic idea is that you would want a constructor of the form

```
template <class V>
constexpr optional(V&& other)
requires (is_derived_from_optional_v<std::remove_cvref_t<V>> && see_below)  // 3
```

where the trait `is_derived_from_optional` detects whether the argument type is a specialization of `optional` or has an unambiguous base class that is a specialization of `optional`. Then,

- If `V` is an lvalue reference, constructor 3 has the additional constraint that the constraints of constructor 1 above must be satisfied (where `U` is the element type of the `optional`).
- If `V` is not a reference (*i.e.*, the argument is an rvalue), then constructor 3 has the additional constraint that the constraints of constructor 2 above must be satisfied, where the argument is `const_cast<std::remove_cv_t<V>&&>(other)`.

Assuming the constraints of constructor 3 are satisfied, it delegates to constructor 1 or 2 depending on the result of overload resolution. (In general, if the argument is a `const` rvalue, then constructor 1 will have to be used since you can't move from a `const` rvalue. However, the constraint above will prevent this from occurring in the dangling `reference_wrapper` case.) Constructors 1 and 2 would need to be made private and have a parameter with a private tag type, so they wouldn't participate in overload resolution from the user's point of view. And constructor 3 might also need a bunch of additional constraints so that its overload resolution priority relative to the other constructors (not shown) is not higher than that of constructors 1 and 2. Like I said, it's not a simple fix.

Answer (score 2):

The reason your code is allowed is because when the underlying object of the `optional` cannot be initialized with rvalue reference, it will fallback to passing the underlying object as `const&`.

---

In fact even this code is allowed:

```cpp
auto ref = std::cref(static_cast<const int&>(1));
```